# Why is this the solution?

Tags: go, tsumego

I'm a very weak go player, playing very occasionally. I however enjoy easy tsumego problems on the train on my phone, as I find it more fun than, say, crosswords or sudoku.

However, the app I use (Tsumego Pro) presented me with this problem, and gave me a "complete" mark on a solution I don't think will work. The hints in the program point to this "solution".

[image: tsumego problem]

As far as I can tell, black is dead and white is fine despite this. In every scenario I play out myself, white is able to kill the black inside the formation and be fine. Is this really the solution? If so, what am I missing? If not, what is?

My apologies if I have screwed up tags, formatting or the question itself, I'm not a regular poster here :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is that killing the black stones doesn't give White an eye.  After White captures the two stones, Black will throw in at the same place he played in #3.  White can capture that stone too, but later in the game the stone above the capture will be placed in atari, and White will have to fill in the "eye" on the right.  Because that can happen, it is a false eye, and the White group is dead.

Comment: I see. If black connects their stones on the left side with those in the top, it protects against being taken by white, and can freely take the top white stone. The kicker to make me realize this was your "later in the game". I was thinking immediate action all the time. That's what I was missing, thank you!